# Loop until the correct data type is inputted using C

Tags: c, c99

Objective is to loop until the user inputs an integer and if they input a different data type it will print out an error and then perform the loop again. However when I input a char the loop falls infinitely. How could perform this without the loop falling infinitely?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int player_input = 0;
    _Bool player_loop = 0;


    while(!player_loop)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Enter position on board: ");
        if((scanf("%d", &player_input)==1))
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", player_input );
            player_loop = 1; //break out of loop
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Please enter an integer!\n");
        }
    }

    fprintf(stdout,"Broke out of loop.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I implemented something similar checking the players username where it would return false if a digit is detected however how I could I do this using integers?

```
bool check_username(char *name)
{
    while (*name)
    {
        if (isdigit(*name))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Please use only characters\n\n");
            return false;
        }
        name++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `int *ptr = player_input;` What did the compiler tell you?

Comment: typo sorry should have been  `&player_input`

Comment: There is a perfectly good way of breaking out of loop, namely the `break` statement ;)

Comment: I believe the `ptr` variable is adding no value here. I'd just pass `&player_input` to `scanf` directly.

Comment: and @Milack27 is correct, the idiom is that you'll use the `&var` right there in the scanf argument, everything else is a suspect.

Comment: @Milack27 yeah I agree its no real value I'll edit the code however it still falls inifinitely

Comment: @TecGuy94 Yes, and...? Did fixing that bug fix the program? Because it was writing all data into la-la-land.

Comment: @Lundin nope it is still falling

Comment: What is the output? The error or the number you typed? Also.. are you able to type an input at each iteration of the loop, or you can type only once at the beginning?

Comment: The problem is that `scanf` does not consume the invalid input, so calling `scanf` again will yield the same result. You can either consume the invalid input up to and including the newline character (for example using the function [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc)), or better: Not use `scanf` at all and use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) instead. See this link for more information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel ah yes that makes sense, thanks!